# MacGyver's infrared goggles

Tags: technology

Suppose Clemont the spy is in a large metropolis in the modern day, northeastern United States. He wants to get through the security of a specific building, but much of his gear has been lost, stolen, or never got off the plane he was on because the baggage people at the airport put the wrong label on his bags and they wound up in Arkansas. He wants to make a night foray, but he doesn't know where the guards are during their rounds.

Clemont gets a brilliant idea. One item misdirected to Arkansas is a pair of nightvision goggles with an option for infrared. If he had those, he could see the guards coming. He decides to hit a bunch of the local stores. What equipment does he need to MacGyver his own infrared goggles?

Also, just how valuable would infrared goggles be in this scenario? My experience of them is pretty much limited to the wonders of Hollywood movie magic.

Comment: I don't see how this is a WorldBuilding question.....then again I have dyslexia and ADHD, so you might be able to enlighten me :)

Comment: @DustinJackson Honestly, I'm not sure how it's _not_ a WorldBuilding question. It presents a clear idea with a request to identify its plausibility and a solution. That being said, it might also be valid on the [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I was thinking more of the first part of your question. Anyway thanks for clarifying that....Dyslexia and ADHD are not a very good combo.

Comment: @Frostfyre This wouldn't fly on EE.SE. We answer questions about electronics design, not where to buy parts for a fictional story.

Comment: @Samuel So I'm proven wrong. I hadn't looked at the terms of the questions there, just knew it existed. I also suspected someone around here was also over there. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a paper clip, a rubber band, a drinking straw, and a ballpoint pen.

Comment: @KSmarts do not forget the chewing gum (I am sure you did not mention it because McGyver always has one of those).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to go on about how the ones I used needed a huge cooling system to work correctly (Bradley fighting vehicle) and were not good for carrying around.

Then I did a quick Google search and found [this](http://www.flir.com/flirone/).  It's a little device that will connect to a smart phone and give you thermal visioning.  So you could mount a phone in some kind of helmet and you have hands free thermal vision...

Comment: A simple solution, certainly. I suspect (hope) the military ones are significantly better than the commercial.

Comment: @Frostfyre Not sure, it was 20 years ago, using already 15-20 year old technology...

Comment: @Frostfyre -- they're limited in resolution due to export controls.  The FLIR One uses a module from FLIR known as the Lepton btw -- this can be integrated into smaller form factors ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about almost any video camera in the last 15 years?

You know those grainy green videos where people have glowing eyes? That's from a infrared video camera. They have been around for a really long time.

The problem with them is they are [providing the infrared light for illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_vision#Active_illumination). That means if anyone else has infrared vision, you look like you're walking around with a flashlight. They are also looking in the near-infrared spectrum. They are not looking at body heat, not because it's not in this spectrum, but because the devices do not have the sensitivity for it.

Comment: Not that that really matters, unless you cover yourself in a heat-suppressing layer to hide your personal infrared signature.

Comment: Actually the green color is not infrared, it's what we used to call starlight.  it amplifies ambient light

Comment: @bowlturner Right, infrared light is clearly *not* green, most of the active-infrared cameras are a combination of features for low-light and near-infrared. So, most of the night vision camera video also appear green from the low-light aspect.

Comment: @Samuel right, it's night vision but not real infrared.  A hot body doesn't really glow in night vision.

Comment: @bowlturner Not correct, near-infrared **is** real infrared. It's a subdivision of the infrared spectrum, near-infrared is not visible by humans.

Comment: Yes all military night vision use the near infrared lights to boost the starlight in real dark, like you said anyone else with it sees you like you're carrying a flash light.  It was not an 'infrared' vision.  That detects the differences in temperature, not just using a wider range of wavelengths to 'see'.

Comment: @bowlturner Infrared vision views light in the infrared spectrum. Vision that detects differences in *temperature* is called **thermal vision**. Thermal vision also uses infrared light, but maps the light frequency to temperature.

Comment: @Samuel  Facepalm!

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the [wikihow page](http://m.wikihow.com/Build-Near-Infrared-Goggles) and is basically plagiarized:

You'll need:

- Goggles (soldering goggles with removable lenses work best)
- 6 200 mW IR LEDs
- Soldering gun
- Theatrical gels (Congo blue LEE C181, and primary red ROSCO 27/LEE C106 )

1.) Paint a pair of goggles black both inside and out everywhere except the lense. They suggest using tape to keep the paint out of the goggles.

2.) Trace the lens of the goggles onto both theatrical photo gels, one 'Congo Blue' and one 'Primary Red'. The combination of these 2 filters will create a low-pass filter, because red blocks blue light and blue blocks red light, but both of them pass through the infra-red light.

3.) Cut the shapes out carefully and glue them to the inside of the lenses. This may require some trimming. First stick the red shape on and on top of that the blue shape so that in order you should have goggles,red,blue.

4.) Take six infra red LEDs and solder three in series (the positive lead of the first LED should branch down to the positive lead of the next LED where it is soldered until this arrangement is leads down to the last LED with the power leads. Both leads should do such.) Repeat with the other three LEDs.

5.) Secure the two LED arrangements to the sides of the goggles and solder some longer wires to the positive and negative leads of the LEDs

6.) Run the wires from the outside to the inside of the goggles and tape them to the proper contacts of a battery. I would recommend a AA for each pair, but this depends on the power consumption for the LEDs. Make sure you read the spec sheets on your LEDs!

Furthermore the goggles let you see near infrared light :)

[Instructibles](http://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-Infrared-Goggles!-For-Under-$10/) also did a tutorial on them. [This site](http://mods-n-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/make-home-made-night-vision-goggles-422825/) also did something on the topic. If you are looking for true, see-in-the dark with all the advanced stuff then I suggest hitting a military surplus store ;)

Comment: I doubt these goggles passively shift light from near-infrared into the visible spectrum. These are more likely **a toy** and make things *appear* like do when looking through night vision goggles.

Comment: @Samuel Because when it comes to "MacGyvering" things toys are about as good as your gonna get less you have your own private factory to crank these things out.

Comment: @Samuel I also did mention the military surplus store...probably easier for an experienced spy to buy a pair of night vision goggles (or even steal them) than to hand make them.

Comment: @Samuel Actually the red and blue filter out the visible spectrum, and as long as there is enough infrared available, moonlit night, or the high power IR LEDS, then it would actually work pretty well for limited ranges.

Comment: @Frank If the visible spectrum is not present, a human **can not see**, that is why it's called the *visible* spectrum. Clearly if anything at all is visible with these goggles, it is because there is still some visible light. Visible light which is, by definition, *not* infrared.

Comment: I don't see why the down vote. I answered OP's question, although it may not be what he was expecting.

Comment: @DustinJackson I downvoted based on my previous comment. Except for the final sentence, where you suggest a military surplus store, your answer (which really is just a duplication of the wikihow) is describing a device that would leave Clemont the spy effectively blind at night. They're simply not infrared goggles.

Comment: @Samuel You are right, I should have said, "most of the visible spectrum", and 'near-infrared"